# Find the derivative. y = arctan(9 tanh(x))

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the derivative. y = arctan(9 tanh(x))

My attempt: $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{1+(9\tanh x)^2}\frac{d}{dx}(9\tanh x)\;\;$ is this right way to solve this problem

Comment: yes, you've got it right.

Comment: can any one help me to right answer or any other way to solve this question

Comment: Are you unsure of the derivative of $\tanh x$?

Comment: What do you need help with? You have it right. The derivative of $\tanh(x)$ is $\text{sech}^2(x)$. So the final answer is $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{9\text{sech}^2(x)}{1 + 81 \tanh^2(x)} = \frac{1}{\cosh^2(x) + 81\sinh^2(x) }.$$

Comment: Easier to put $\tan y = \tanh x$, $\frac{d \tan y}{dx} = \frac{1}{1+y^2} \frac{dy}{dx}$.